# Rails 4 - Remove attribute name from error message for associated model presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, rails-i18n

I have two models `user_item` and `user_item_images`.

**user_item.rb**

```
has_many :user_item_images, dependent: :destroy
validates :user_item_images, presence: { message: "You must include a picture" }
```

**user_item_images.rb**

```
belongs_to :user_item
```

I have a nested form with only one `user_item_image` field which is `:picture`.  When I submit an empty form I get this message

> User item images You must include a picture

How do I make it so that the message instead says

> You must include a picture

I don't know how to edit the en.yml file because the error is on the presence of another model and not an attribute of a model.

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails) but the answer is too broad and I think I need a custom validation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fully custom validation error message with Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808547/fully-custom-validation-error-message-with-rails)

Comment: I don't think so.  That answer is vague and I believe I needed a custom validation to solve my issue.

Comment: Yeah, you need custom validation. Check out these 2 answers on that question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10635913/2266827, http://stackoverflow.com/a/33292528/2266827. They'll give you what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom validation instead:

```
has_many :user_item_images, dependent: :destroy
validate :has_a_picture

private

def has_a_picture
  errors.add(:base, 'You must include a picture') if user_item_images.none?
end
```

Comment: Why should I still include the `presence: ...`?

Comment: I actually tried using your [monkey patch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34347478/4584963).  It worked great for the picture attribute on `user_item_images` doesn't work for presence of the association.

Comment: I was getting this error message `"undefined method 'none?' for :user_item_images:Symbol"` so I changed the method to `... if self.user_item_images.none?`.  My only question is that I need to be certain that a `user_item` can never be created unless there is an associated `user_item_image`.  Will this validation accomplish this?

Comment: I noticed your edit.  Would the `self` in `self.user_item_images.none?` be redundant?

Comment: @user4584963 - it should prevent that on the application level, however there are other situation you need to be prepared for like user creating item with image and then deleting the image. It would be best to have some sort of db constraint to be 100% sure.

Comment: @user4584963 - `self` is a default reciever and is only required to make a difference between local variable and method. Since there is no local variable with that name, `self` is not required.

Comment: Some sort of db constraint as in another validation?  Something like a `before_destroy` on `user_item_image` that checks to be sure there is at least one `user_item_image` associated?

Answer (score -1):

For that, in your user_item_images model you need:

  `validates :picture, presence: true`

You may also want to look into whether you have data modeling issues to resolve. Regardless, your current validation only validates that the association exists. So, when you submit an user_item_images form with an empty picture field the validation that fails is the one in your user_item model. Rather than attempt to change the content of association presence validation error message, add a validation for the picture column in the user_item_images. That way if picture is empty, it will raise 'You must include a picture'.

I'll also comment that having the presence validation :user_item_images on the user_item model shouldn't be necessary and likely indicates a larger data modelling issue that you need to resolve.

Comment: I think you might be confused as to how my models are set up.  A `user_item` should never exist unless there is an associated `user_item_image`.  The reason I have the message `"You must include a picture"` is because that is the only attribute a user is able to add to a `user_item_image`.

Answer (score -3):

There's no need to write extra code. You should use Rails' built in I18n to customise ActiveRecord error messages.

Inside `config/locales/en.yml`

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user_item:
          attributes:
            user_item_images:
              presence: "You must include a picture"
```

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work.  With this change I am still getting the same error message with the attribute name still present.

Comment: You may also need to add format: '%{message}' in user_item_images:

Comment: it should be blank, not presence [reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-scopes)